# Windows 10 won't respond to network requests

Tags: networking, windows-10, firewall, webserver, windows-10-v1803

I'm having an issue where my Windows 10 PC won't respond to network requests.

Windows 10 Pro
Version: 1803

Steps:

1. Setup my network with the Private profile
2. Setup static IP on my local network
3. Made sure to make the PC discoverable on the network
4. Made sure the allow inbound rules to the correct applications in Windows firewall
5. Spun up a little NodeJS server for testing port 8080.
6. Firewall prompted to allow inbound connections to NodeJS.exe Accepted
7. NodeJS is bound to all network interfaces 0.0.0.0
8. I go to another machine on the same network hit http://PC_IP_ADDRESS:8080 chrome says the connection is made and waiting for server
9. I check NodeJS console, and the request has shown up.
10. Chrome is still waiting, eventually times out.
11. I try again, check in Resource Monitor that the connection is getting through ok, it shows up fine, sits around, then times out. Says bytes received (i assume the request from the other machine) but sent 0 bytes.
12. Checked firewall logs and shows the connection was accepted.

Not really sure what else I can do? I've done a fresh install of windows 10 also to make sure it wasn't a random setting and it's still doing the same thing.

Even tried with the firewall disabled and still the same, so I think the firewall settings must be ok

Answer (score 0):

go to control panel -> network connections -> ethernet adapter(or the network adapter your connecting with). right click on it goto status. then details.

are the iPv4 address, subnetmask , default gateway and dns server correct ??

Answer (score 0):

The answer above was correct, so I was adding my static IP settings via Windows 10 > Settings > Network & Internet > Wifi. Then clicking on my Wifi and choosing to edit IP settings.

However the problem seemed to be that when i type in the subnet 255.255.255.0 for some reason there's a bug which defaults it back to just 255, which then gets interpreted as 255.255.255.255 so causes a problem with responses being sent back over the network.

I've now changed those settings back to Automatic (DHCP) and used the method above Control Panel > Network Connections -> Wifi Adaptor to set the IPv4 static settings and it works perfectly!